# Rewrite rule with pagination .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre

I have a URL like this:

`http://example.com/category/title` which comes from the link `http://example.com/cview.php?url=title`

I want to create pagination and to be like `http://example.com/category/title/page/1` or
`http://example.com/category/title/1`
this comes from `http://example.com/cview.php?url=title&pageno=1`.

I have tried this in `.htaccess` without success

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$/([^/]+)/?$ /cview.php?url=$2&pageno=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$/([^/]+)/?$ /cview.php?url=$2&pageno=$1 [L]
> ```

You have an erroneous `$` (end-of-string anchor) in the middle of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. You also appear to have the backreferences `$1` and `$2` the wrong way round. You are also allowing an optional trailing slash, yet your example URLs do not use this. (An *optional* trailing slash potentially creates a duplicate content issue.)

If you allow both `/category/title/page/1` and `/category/title/1` then you are potentially creating a duplicate content issue. Presumably you are only linking to one of these URL formats?

Since the page number is a "number" then it makes sense to just match numbers, rather than anything - this also helps to avoid conflicts with other directives.

It doesn't look like you need the conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) that check the request does not map to a file or directory, since I wouldn't expect a request of the form `/category/title/page/1` to map to a file or directory anyway?

Try the following instead (without the `RewriteCond` directives):

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)(?:/page)?/(\d+)$ /cview.php?url=$1&pageno=$2 [L]
```

This matches both `/category/title/page/<num>` and `/category/title/<num>`. The optional subpattern `(?:/page)` is non-capturing, so that it doesn't mess up the numbering of the backreferences.

Bear in mind also that the order of the rules in `.htaccess` is important in order to avoid conflicts.

Comment: YES! It worked! thank you very much! This way it worked, but I tried to the link: http://thedomain.com/view which comes from http://thedomain.com/view.php with this code in htaccess RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f I wanted to be the same way, http://thedomain.com/view/2 but I got 500 error